# Getting empty state after calling the handleSubmit event from setInterval function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const QuizPage = () => {
    const [allanswers,setToAllAnswer] = useState([])               // have all answers
  const startTimer = (tim) => {
    const tims = tim * 60 * 1000;
    const countdowntime = new Date().getTime() + tims; // time for test

    var x = setInterval(() => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const distance = countdowntime - now;
    const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      handleSubmit();                // this is returning empty state

    } else {
      setTimerHours(hours);
      setTimerMinutes(minutes);
      setTimerSeconds(seconds);
    }
  },1000);
};
const handleStart = () => {       // test start
  let tim = 1;                   // test time in minutes
  startTimer(tim);

};
const handleSubmit = () => {     // on test end
  console.log(allanswers);
};
```

if this handleSubmit is called by onClick() event it show list containing answers.

NOTE: all the required states are already defined in original code.

Comment: The callback you place in the `setInterval` has a stale reference to `handleSubmit` which has a stale reference to `allanswers`

Comment: Can you suggest a sollution  please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `useRef` you can ensure to always have a reference to the newest state object.

```
const [allAnswers, setAllAnswers] = useState([]);
const stateRef = useRef();
stateRef.current = allAnswers;


const handleSubmit = () => { console.log(stateRef.current) };
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you forgot to call the **setToAllAnswer** function and that's why the state is empty.

Here is the running example

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const HomePage = () => {
  const [allanswers, setToAllAnswer] = useState([])               // have all answers
  const startTimer = (tim) => {
    console.log("start timer");
    const tims = tim * 1 * 1000;
    const countdowntime = new Date().getTime() + tims; // time for test

    var x = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("enter in interval");
      const now = new Date().getTime();
      const distance = countdowntime - now;
      const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      console.log("distance=======", distance);
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        handleSubmit();                // this is returning empty state

      } else {
        // setTimerHours(hours);
        // setTimerMinutes(minutes);
        // setTimerSeconds(seconds);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };
  const handleStart = () => {       // test start
    let tim = 1;                   // test time in minutes
    startTimer(tim);

  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {     // on test end
    console.log(allanswers);
  };
  const setAnswer = () => {
    setToAllAnswer(["a"]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleStart}>start</button>
      <button onClick={setAnswer}>set answer</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: No, actually this is a small portion of code, actual code contains more than 7 files...pls consider  that my state is not empty as i described in question that on submitting the ans array has answers but when time ends and the handlesubmit fn is called it return same array as empty

Comment: Abhishek, Please try to run the above code. you are not able to get the answers from setInterval and I have got the answers from setInterval. firstly click on "Set answer" button then click the "Start" button to get the answers in setInterval